# Angularjs ng-click expression to alert when more then 4 selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a large angularjs app... I am trying to make 4 div's selectable at a single time otherwise end user should receive a alert saying you can't select 5th...

Here is where I have reached so far,

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
    <table id="myTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="field in fieldList">
          <td>
            <span>{{field.name}}</span>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 15px;">
            <div ng-click="$('.tick').length >= 4 ? (!selected) : (selected = !selected)" ng-class="{'notick' : !selected, 'tick': selected}"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("ap", []);

app.controller("con", function($scope) {
  $scope.fieldList = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Number 1"
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Number 2"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Number 3"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Number 4"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Number 5"
  }];
});
```

**CSS**

```
.tick {
  color: red;
}

.notick {
  color: grey;
}
```

Real code is different but I tried to make it work here as closely as possible, A user should only be able to select 4 divs at any given time otherwise a alert should stop them,

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/baa2G/110/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this with the following angular syntax which should be preferred over mixing Jquery syntax in angular.

your html changes will be

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="field in fieldList">
          <td>
            <div ng-click="checkCount($index)" ng-class="{'tick' : field.clicked}">{{field.name}}</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

P.S : i have kept single td element to put the event on wnere text is displayed.

and in your controller.

```
$scope.checkCount = function(index) {
    if ($scope.fieldList[index].clicked !== true) {
      if ($scope.clickedElement === 4) {
        alert("Only 4 div can be selected.")
      } else {
        $scope.fieldList[index].clicked = true;
        $scope.clickedElement++;
      }
    }
    else
    {
     $scope.fieldList[index].clicked = false;
     $scope.clickedElement--;
    }
  }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hudrozxd/1/

Comment: thank you very much, it solved half of my problem, but I want to these clicks can be reversed which I am not able to do with your code :( , +1 for the effort

Comment: @Mathematics you will have to add one else condition for that. updated the answer